# Emails can't download to Outlook (dovecot, sendmail, CentOS)

Tags: centos, sendmail, outlook, dovecot

I installed dovecot with

```
yum install dovecot
```

Added the following configuration options to `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
disable_plaintext_auth = NO
listen =*
```

To `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` added:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

When I type `dovecot -n | less`, I get:

```
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.5 (Final) 
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

I'm able to send email via Outlook and I see it on my mail server, but I can't download email via Outlook.

**EDIT1:**
The log shows the following, when trying to connect:

```
Aug 1 23:04:49 test dovecot: pop3(user1): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
Aug 1 23:04:49 test dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<user2>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.151, lip=192.168.0.150, mpid=31779 Aug 1 23:04:49 test dovecot: pop3(user2): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
```

The used Local Delivery Agent is sendmail.

**EDIT2:**
After setting `mail_location` in dovecot to `maildir:/var/spool/mail/%u` I got the following error message in Thunderbird:
    Couln't not open Inbox: Internal error occurred

`$MAIL` of user1 is set to `/var/spool/mail/user1`

**EDIT3:**
I think i fixed it by setting `mail_location` to `mbox:~/var/spool/mail/%u:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u`. But now it only works for `user1`, not `user2`.

Comment: @NickW
I check mail on server mail 
"[user1@test ~]$ mail
Heirloom Mail version 12.4 7/29/08.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/user1": 3 messages
>   1 root                  Thu Jul 31 23:04  59/2585  "testing mail"
    2 root                  Fri Aug  1 00:17  21/728   "test user"
    3 user2                 Fri Aug  1 22:56  45/1387  "testmail"
& 
"

Comment: Does dovecot has the right permissions to create `/var/spool/mail/user2` if necessary and to create files and dirs inside? And what is the error message you get (client and log)?

Comment: @sebix
Thank you , i think i that my proplem 
i use command `chmod 777 /var/spool/mail
chmod 777 /var/spool/mail/user1
chmod 777 /var/spool/mail/user2`

but if i add new acc , example `user3` , i need more command , can you fix it ?

Comment: Please don't set everyting world-read- and even worse -writeable!!! Give sendmail and dovecot the ability to write there, via their group, so `chgrp mail /dir` and so one. And please learn some linux basics, otherwise you will face plant it sooner or later.

Comment: @sebix I am understand , thank for help

Comment: I've tried to clean up some of the comments. Please make sure that when you edit your question or try something new, that you also update the question with the new information and remove any old information that is no longer relevant.